Is it possible to assign multiple entity labels to a single word/span in any free annotation library?
I noticed that this question went unanswered, so I'd like to revive it for those new to NLP.
Is there an annotation tool/library that accommodates the assigning of multiple labels to a single word? For example, given the instance of the word "fox", I'd like to assign it multiple entity labels corresponding to its Domain, Kingdom, Phylum, etc., respectively.
I understand that SpaCy doesn't allow for this by default, so now looking elsewhere. ProdiGy does allow for this, but is not free.  Open to workarounds, of course. Thank you!
